# Creating tab bar application on iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have developed an iPhone application based on Tab bar & Navigation bar and i have done that successfully.

now i want to create the same application with some minor different requirement on the Ipad the problem that the same Design structure i used for the iphone is not working on Ipad here is what i am doing:

```
 - ViewController  (login)
 - ViewController  (List of devices)
```

now here is the problem

```
 - ViewController (have tab bar view controller)
```

the ViewController is not calling the first tab which was successfully done in the iphone  is there different between iphone tab bar based application and ipad?

[In my TabViewController]

```
 IBOutlet UITabBarController *TabNavigator;
```

connected through the xib file 
in my viewDidLoad handler i use:

```
 self.view =  self.TabNavigator.view;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, Personally i don't know the logic but it's strange in the iphone I used to do the following from the Application Delegate to call the tab bar controller:

```
-(void) vLoadTabViewController
{
  for (int i = 0; i < [[window subviews] count]; i++) 
  {
    UIView * subView = [[window subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
  }

  TabNavigationViewController *ooTabNavigationViewController = [TabNavigationViewController alloc]; 
  [window addSubview:ooTabNavigationViewController.view];
  [ooTabNavigationViewController release];
}
```

When I removed the release line on the iPad everything worked fine.